# How to find actual path of the image in php

Tags: php, encoding, base64, file-get-contents

I want to find real path of the image. Simply I want to store `base64` of the image but not the image on the server. simply I want to use this code.

```
$image = file_get_content(filepath);
$encoded = base64_encode($image);
```

in file path I just want to pass the file path. How can I do this. Or any other method to store `base64` only not image on the server using php.

Comment: The actual path of what image?

Comment: when I select file in php using input:file I just want full address of the image so I can convert that image to base64. without uploading it

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The file doesn't exist on the server if it hasn't been uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing :

If you're using PHP to upload an image to the server and want to store the base64 version of it :

HTML :

```
<input type="file" name="myimage">
```

PHP :

```
if(isset($_FILES["myimage"])) {

    //file has been submitted, you might want to check for errors

    $image = file_get_contents($_FILES["myimage"]["tmp_name"]);
    $encoded = base64_encode($image);

    //store the encoded version
}
```

If you don't intend to use PHP to upload images, and want to store immediately base64 version of an image, you can't do that using PHP as it doesn't make sense at all (PHP has no access whatsoever to the user's file system, and thank God it doesn't). Instead, you'd need to do some Javascript.

Please remember that this snippet is for example purpose, you'd have to check the upload for errors and stuff if you're willing to use it in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a file via a `<input name="picture" />` tag you can get the file path with `$_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"]`.